# How good is to apply React Context API for all screens

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native, react-context

Currently I have four contexts that wrap all my routes (as shown bellow) so that I don't have lost providers all around my app screens and components. As far as I know, when I modify the value of a context variable, every component that uses it will update too, what can lead to memory problems, but my question is: if my providers, that wrap all routes/screens, even the ones that uses no context variable, may cause the same memory related problems.

```
 <AuthProvider>
  <SelectedBranchProvider>
    <SelectedEventProvider>
      <DrawerFormProvider>
        <RightDrawerNavigator />
      </DrawerFormProvider>
    </SelectedEventProvider>
  </SelectedBranchProvider>
</AuthProvider>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The danger with context isn't memory issues, it's unneeded re-renders. The way Context is implemented defeats some of React's diffing, so a change in Context can cause a re-render in any component that uses the same Context, even if the value that changes is unused in the component.

If you have a small app, or only rarely change what's in your context, you'll probably never hit these limitations. Good use cases for context are things that would require many re-renders and rarely change, like user language or app theme.

The docs for Context have a caveats section that goes over this: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#caveats

Here's a blog post with a good example of how this can cause re-renders: https://blog.logrocket.com/pitfalls-of-overusing-react-context/

Comment: Just split 1 big context into multiple contexts with each has states/update related to each other, probably with the help of https://github.com/diegohaz/constate. Most people just use Context poorly and blame.

Comment: That library looks cool, and I'm sure there is more to Context that I'm overlooking. But since there are solid alternatives that don't need the extra overhead, I don't see it as a first-class solution. It's also very un-opinionated, which seems potentially messy on a large project.